# Developer story has too narrow tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, developer-story

I see the following in my profile when pointing to exclamation icon:

> [image: Too narrow tooltip]

Comment: I would actually go the other way of the tooltip should probably just stop of "You are open but not actively look for a job" so that people click into it a tooltip should not really contain the whole message of a content area on a page

Comment: Wouldnt this be a part of [New activity bug list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page)?

Comment: @SurajRao Developer Story is SO only thing, so I don't think it should be posted on MSE. BTW I have several posts there already.

Answer (score 5):

CSS is hard :(

We've got a PR to fix this ready. However, we're currently in a code freeze due to the upcoming holidays. Since this isn't a critical bug, it'll be merged in January when we're back.

I'll mark this report as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) so it will be clear to other staff that a fix has already been implemented in the codebase.

---

**Update**: This fix has been merged and will be pushed out in the next deployment.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! Did you know we have a Q&A site that can help you with your CSS problems? ;-) For future reference, [[meta-tag:status-planned]] might be a better choice for cases like this, as [[meta-tag:status-completed]] might confuse some people into thinking that the fix had been deployed and then re-reporting it as a regression. Not too big of a deal, not even big enough for me to retag, and, ultimately, it's a judgment call. The major drawback with [[meta-tag:status-planned]] is, obviously, that you have to come back later and update it to [[meta-tag:status-completed]].

Comment: Ah thanks @CodyGray, I'm still new to interacting on Meta so I appreciate the feedback! I'd agree with you about [meta-tag:status-planned] would have made more sense since the fix isn't live yet and could lead to confusion.